# Need c# code optimized to insert CSV rows to MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, sql-insert

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish ... At the click of a button, I want to:

1. Copy existing data of the live "users" table to "old_users" table for backup purposes
2. Truncate the existing "new_users" table to prepare it to accept new rows
3. Parse through a CSV file to insert data into the "new_users" table
4. Truncate the existing "users" table and then copy data of the "new_users" table to "users" table

I am not a daily programmer and haven't created a program in a very long time. But I've piece-mealed some code together to get something that kinda works. Below is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Common;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ValidationImport
{
public partial class ValiationImport : Form
{
    public ValiationImport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnImportToDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new SshClient("1.1.1.1", "[username]", "[password]")) // establishing ssh connection to server where MySql is hosted
            {
                client.Connect();
                if (client.IsConnected)
                {
                    var portForwarded = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 3306, "127.0.0.1", 3306);
                    client.AddForwardedPort(portForwarded);
                    portForwarded.Start();
                    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;PORT=3306;UID=[username];PASSWORD=[password];DATABASE=[dbname]")) // MySql database credentials
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        // Copying over the users table (with structure and indexes) to the old_users table. Truncating the new_users table to prepare for new data.
                        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("DROP TABLE test_old_users; CREATE TABLE test_old_users LIKE test_users; INSERT test_old_users SELECT * FROM test_users; TRUNCATE TABLE test_new_users;", con))
                        {
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                        string fileName = "";
                        // Select the Validation file to import
                        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
                        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                            fileName = dlg.FileName;

                        if (fileName != "")
                        {
                            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(fileName))
                            {
                                parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                                parser.SetDelimiters("|");
                                parser.ReadLine(); // Skip the first row of field title headers
                                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                                {
                                    //Copy each row individually over to the MySql table
                                    string[] row = parser.ReadFields();

                                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO test_new_users (`Indv Id`, `Last Name`, `First Name`, `Middle Name`, `Birth date`, `Indv Addr Line 1`, `Indv Addr Line 2`, `Indv Addr Line 3`, `Indv City`, `Indv State`, `Indv Zip`, `Indv Country`, `Local Id`, `Local Name`, `Local User Id`, `Uniserv Id`, `Uniserv Name`, `Uniserv User Id`, `Chapter Name`, `Chapter User Id`, `Employer Id`, `Employer Name`, `Work Location Id`, `Work Location Name`, `Work Location User Id`, `Group Id`, `Group Name`, `Group Type Id`, `Group Type Name`, `SEA P01`, `Home  Phone`, `Home Phone principal Ind`, `Home Phone Unlisted Ind`, `Mobile Phone`, `Mobile Phone Principal Ind`, `Mobile Phone Unlisted Ind`, `Home Email`, `Home Email Principal Ind`, `Work Email`, `Work Email Principal Ind`, `Other Email`, `Other Email Principal Ind`) VALUES (@IndvId, @LastName, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @BirthDate, @IndvAddrLine1, @IndvAddrLine2, @IndvAddrLine3, @IndvCity, @IndvState, @IndvZip, @IndvCountry, @LocalId, @LocalName, @LocalUserId, @UniservId, @UniservName, @UniservUserId, @ChapterName, @ChapterUserId, @EmployerId, @EmployerName, @WorkLocationId, @WorkLocationName, @WorkLocationUserId, @GroupId, @GroupName, @GroupTypeId, @GroupTypeName, @SEAP01, @HomePhone, @HomePhonePrincipalInd, @HomePhoneUnlistedInd, @MobilePhone, @MobilePhonePrincipalInd, @MobilePhoneUnlistedInd, @HomeEmail, @HomeEmailPrincipalInd, @WorkEmail, @WorkEmailPrincipalInd, @OtherEmail, @OtherEmailPrincipalInd);", con))
                                    {
                                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IndvId", row[0]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", row[1]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", row[2]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", row[3]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", row[4]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IndvAddrLine1", row[5]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IndvAddrLine2", row[6]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IndvAddrLine3", row[7]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IndvCity", row[8]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IndvState", row[9]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IndvZip", row[10]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IndvCountry", row[11]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocalId", row[12]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocalName", row[13]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocalUserId", row[14]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniservId", row[15]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniservName", row[16]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniservUserId", row[17]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChapterName", row[18]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChapterUserId", row[19]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployerId", row[20]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployerName", row[21]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkLocationId", row[22]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkLocationName", row[23]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkLocationUserId", row[24]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupId", row[25]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupName", row[26]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupTypeId", row[27]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupTypeName", row[28]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEAP01", row[29]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhone", row[30]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhonePrincipalInd", row[31]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhoneUnlistedInd", row[32]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobilePhone", row[33]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobilePhonePrincipalInd", row[34]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobilePhoneUnlistedInd", row[35]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeEmail", row[36]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeEmailPrincipalInd", row[37]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkEmail", row[38]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkEmailPrincipalInd", row[39]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtherEmail", row[40]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtherEmailPrincipalInd", row[41]);
                                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Copying over the new_users table (with structure and indexes) to the users table.
                        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("DROP TABLE test_users; CREATE TABLE test_users LIKE test_new_users; INSERT test_users SELECT * FROM test_new_users;", con))
                        {
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    client.Disconnect();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Client cannot be reached...");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

It's all "working" ... except I get an error when in debug mode in visual studio. Something about how it's taking too long to process. Oh, just so you know, there's around 38,000 rows in the CSV file that has to be inserted into the table.

If you have any suggestions or new code for me to try out, I'd greatly appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: For the import portion, you should be able to create the command object for inserting once, add it's parameters once, and prepare it, before the loop; then, just set the parameter values and execute for each iteration. As for the first "backup" portion; are you sure it's working? Last time I worked with MySqlCommands, their default mode did not allow for multiple queries in a single execute.

Comment: If the slowness is at the parsing part, you can use ExcelDataReader to parse the file and it's fast. I can share a sample code if it's your problem.

Comment: The slowness is at the INSERTing part. It got through about 2,000 rows before popping up that error about it taking a long time. I'm only parsing 1 row at a time and INSERTing that row into the MySql table. I'm open to suggestions as to how to do it better. Uueerdo, can you go into more detail about the 1st half of your comment? And yes, I'm sure the backup portion is working correctly using multiple queries in a single execute command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many scenarios where you end up looping over data running the same queries repeatedly for different data, you can help speed things up by preparing the query once, before looping begins.

```
using (var cn = new MySqlConnection(...))
using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
{
   // Setup command
   cmd.CommandText = "Some query";
   var param1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@paramName1", MySQLDbType.sometype);
   var param2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@paramName2", MySQLDbType.sometype);
   cmd.Prepare();

   // get data

   // loop over data
   foreach(var d in data)
   {
      param1.Value = d.somevalue;
      param2.Value = d.anothervalue;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

You can also address the parameters by index, like `cmd.Parameters[0].Value`.

Preparing the statement in this manner reduces the overhead of the work done to parse the query itself every iteration.

---

In one situation I had to deal with, I found the best solution was to combine the above with an INSERT query that used multiple values lists, of the form `INSERT INTO X(a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?)`. It made the actual implementation much more complicated (having to appropriately handle the "leftovers" at the end that would not fill all values lists), and relied on addressing the parameters by index; but did make a difference.

---

Edit: pseudo code to handle ssh connection closing on you

```
connect = true
Open datasource
while (data remains)
{
   if (connect)
   {
      init ssh client
      init mysql connection
      init mysql command
      connect = false
   }
   while (data remains and enough time remaining)
   {
      get next data
      set command parameters
      execute command
   }
   if (not enough time remaining)
   {
       close current connection and client
       connect = true
   }
}
```

Comment: So in your "// get data" section. I should be parsing through the CSV file and dumping it into a datatable or something?

Comment: Basically yeah. In the context of your question, that could be the parser init, and you could replace the foreach with your while and begin each iteration with the `ReadFields` call. Then just do something like `param1.Value = row[0];`. There is nothing special about the collection-loop logic I used as an example, it was just good for brevity. The import parts are setting up the command, defining its parameters, and preparing it _before_ the loop... and then assigning (rather than adding) parameter values in the loop.

Comment: I did all of what you suggested above and I'm still getting the same error. Here's the exact error I'm getting: ContextSwitchDeadlock occurred
Message: Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' has detected a problem in [exe file location]

Comment: Apparently, calling `Application.DoEvents();` fixes the problem. It takes about 15 minutes to parse and insert 38,000 rows into the remote MySql table, but whatever ... it works, lol. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ugh ... I think the ssh tunnel timed out at around 10 minutes. It got through about 1/2 of the file. I think I'm going to have to parse through the data and save it to a datatable first. Then maybe create a huge insert statement so the ssh tunnel is only open for a couple seconds?

Comment: I've never had to do db access over ssh, so I couldn't say anything helpful for that. But, your use of DoEvents suggests you're talking about your program not responding. You can avoid that by using BackgroundWorker (and even report progress to the UI).

Comment: One thing I can think for the ssh time limit (if you know it) is to keep track of how much time you have left, then, when nearing the end of your window, open a new connection (ssh and mysql), reinit a new command and continue with where you left off.